# Avoiding memory leaks with Commanded in an aggregate that doesn't produce an event

Tags: memory-leaks, elixir, cqrs, event-sourcing, commanded

An application built with Commanded 0.17.2 on Elixir 1.7.4 frequently runs out of memory. An investigation found that the memory leak seems to be caused by a growing number of aggregate instances, which are never stopped.

The aggregate in question receives commands triggered by an external system. In some cases, the `execute` function returns an event, and in some other cases, the command should be ignored and it therefore returns `nil` (as described by the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/commanded/0.17.2/aggregates.html#command-functions)).

```
def execute(%RemoteThing{}, %ImportRemoteThing{deleted: true}), do: nil
```

It seems that every time `nil` is returned and not an event, the aggregate instance is kept alive indefinately. This happens even though both a timeout and a lifespan are attached, which explicitly intends something else:

```
defmodule RemoteThing.Lifespan do
  @behaviour Commanded.Aggregates.AggregateLifespan

  def after_event(_event), do: :stop
  def after_command(_command), do: :stop
end

dispatch(
  ImportRemoteThing,
  to: RemoteThing,
  lifespan: RemoteThing.Lifespan,
  timeout: 15_000
)
```

I suspect this to be a bug in [Commanded](https://github.com/commanded/commanded/blob/releases/v0.17.0/lib/commanded/aggregates/aggregate.ex#L346):

```
defp aggregate_lifespan_timeout(_context, []), do: :infinity
```

One way to avoid the memory leak could be to produce an event, even if no one requires it. This would lead to a polluted persisted event store instead of the volatile memory, and would therefore probably cause even bigger problems in the long run.

I am now looking for a way to stop the aggregate instance in case the `execute` function returns an `nil`. Every idea for a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been fixed and will be available in the [next release of Commanded](https://github.com/commanded/commanded/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes).

Pull reques [#210](https://github.com/commanded/commanded/pull/210) extended aggregate lifespan behaviour to include `after_error/1` and `after_command/1` callbacks.

Previously you only had to define an `after_event/1` callback function to implement the `Commanded.Aggregates.AggregateLifespan` behaviour:

```
defmodule BankAccountLifespan do
  @behaviour Commanded.Aggregates.AggregateLifespan

  def after_event(%BankAccountClosed{}), do: :stop
  def after_event(_event), do: :infinity
end
```

Now you must also define `after_command/1` and `after_error/1` callback functions:

```
defmodule BankAccountLifespan do
  @behaviour Commanded.Aggregates.AggregateLifespan

  def after_event(%BankAccountClosed{}), do: :stop
  def after_event(_event), do: :infinity

  def after_command(%CloseAccount{}), do: :stop
  def after_command(_command), do: :infinity

  def after_error(:invalid_initial_balance), do: :stop
  def after_error(_error), do: :stop
end
```

The `after_command/1` callback would allow you to stop the aggregate when no events are produced.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Any idea for a workaround as long as the fix is not released?

Comment: The PR is merged AFAICT, so `{:dep_from_git, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/my_dep.git"}` should be good enough.

Comment: As a workaround you could potentially use the local `Registry` (named `Commanded.Registration.LocalRegistry`) to identify running aggregate process and gracefully terminate them as needed.